# How to save matplotlib plot as a .png file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a piece of code that I have acquired from a collaborator in work. This piece of code produces a plot like the one seen below.
[example image of a plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJJLZ.png)

It does this by referencing another function in another piece of code; which I do not want to alter in any way.

What I would like to do is to write a piece of code that saves this plot as a png file i.e. I am looking for a function that i can put the other function as a variable that would save it is as a png/ jpeg file.

Code:

Here is the code:

```
for file in files:
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 connection = sqlite3.connect( file )
 animalPool = AnimalPool( )
 animalPool.loadAnimals( connection )

# show the mask of animals at frame 300


 animalPool.showMask( 701 )
```

It is calling the following function:

```
    def showMask(self, t ):
    '''
    show the mask of all animals in a figure
    '''

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim(90, 420)
    ax.set_ylim(-370, -40)

    for animal in self.getAnimalList():                    
        mask = animal.getBinaryDetectionMask( t )
        mask.showMask( ax=ax )

    plt.show()
```

I have already tried the matplotlib "savefig" function, but this just saves a blank image.

I am very new to coding, and am trying to learn on the fly, so if this question is not well worded or explained please let me know what is confusing, because I'm also learning how to ask questions about this kind of thing.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You tried `savefig` and it didn't work? Perhaps if you post a [mcve] for that code someone will be able to suggest how to make it work.

Comment: if it saves a blank image then put the function "nearer" to where the figure is created, it needs to be after any code that creates the figure, but before anything that starts creating a new figure

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Updated the question to include code.

Comment: The code you posted does not include your attempt at `savefig`, even though it is the crucial part of the question.

Comment: After `plt.show()` is called, a new figure is created. That is why you end up with a blank image when you call `plt.savefig()` after `plt.show()`. I know you don't want to make any changes within the function. However, adding `plt.savefig("plot.png", format="png")` on the line before `plt.show()` would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions that produce matplotlib plots should take a figure or axes as input and only optionally create those if needed. They should return the created objects for further use. Finally, they should not call `plt.show()`, or if they must, provide an opt-out option.
For example, for a single axes plotting function, it could look like

```
def plottingfunction(*arguments, ax=None, show=True):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    else:
        fig = ax.figure

    # do something with fig and ax here, e.g.
    line, = ax.plot(*arguments)

    if show:
        plt.show()

    return fig, ax, line
```

If you adhere to such structure, it's easy to do whatever you need to after calling the function

```
fig, _, _ = plottingfunction([1,2,3], [3,2,4], show=False)
fig.savefig("myplot.png")
plt.show()
```